# setInterval() not working with rotate

Tags: javascript, intervals

I have an image. I have written some code that will rotate it over en over,
but the `setInterval()` function is not working.

Please can you tell me why?

```
var star = document.getElementById('star');
setInterval(function() {star.style.transform = "rotate(10deg)"; },10);
```

Comment: Increment the degree each time. You are assigning the same degree over en over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increment the degree value on each function call, simply do it using a variable. In your case it will always stay on `10degree` rotate.

**DEMO:**

```js
var star = document.getElementById('star'),
  deg = 10;
setInterval(function() {
  star.style.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
  deg = (deg + 10) % 360
}, 10);
```

```css
#star {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="star"></div>
```

---

You can use [css animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation) here

```css
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }75% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#star {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation: anim .36s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="star"></div>
```

Comment: maximum degree is 360. But you are incrementing it indefinitely.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy `maximum degree is 360` - I disagree, do you have anything to support your claim?

Answer (score 0):

Small sample:

```js
var ready = function() {
 
  var 
    star = document.getElementById('star'),
    degree = 0;
  
  setInterval(function() {
    
    /* Every 10ms degree variable increase its value by 1 */
    star.style.transform = "rotate(" + ++degree +"deg)"; }, 10
  );
};
```

```css
#star {
  
  margin-left: 100px; 
  margin-top: 40px; 
  width: 60px; 
  border: 1px solid; 
  padding: 20px; 
}
```

```html
<body onload="ready()">
  <div id="star">
    <h1>Yay!</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```